# Having troubles with a python text split script

Tags: python

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines=f.read()
    lines=lines.split('>')
    lines=['>'+x for x in lines[1:]]
    for x in lines:
        file_name=x.split('\n')[0][1:]  #use this variable to create the new file
        fil=open(file_name+'.txt','w')
        fil.write(x)
        fil.close()
```

This script is supposed to split up a large txt file into an individual small text files. But when I run the script in windows PowerShell the following error happens.

Thank you

[image: error picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines=f.read()
    lines=lines.split('>')
    for l in lines:
        file_name=l.split('\n')[0]
        fil=open(f"{file_name}.txt",'w') 
        for x in lines:
            fil.write(x)
        fil.close()
```

Comment: @7331lol Sorry I don;t understand the question.

Comment: @7331lol Can you give me a mock sample of what your data.txt' looks like?

Comment: My question was malformed the error is the newest files never have all the information when I use the normal way of just using the next line. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @7331lol I updated my original answer. Run that and see what you think.

Comment: The files generated aren't split up, however I will have to fix this tomorrow. Thank you for your help, good luck to England in the UEFA.

Comment: Doesn't really matter

Comment: @7331lol Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: I am taking a different approach as I realized a way more efficient way, thank you though.